# Using Wald Test with unknown distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am stuck on the following task:

> They conducted an experiment on different medicines. For placebo there
>   are $80$ patients and $45$ complications, for medicine A, there are $75$ patients and
>   $26$ complications. Test success of medicine A against placebo on significance level $0.05$.

I have read a [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) and I don't understand how to formulate the hypothesis.

Maybe it is better to use chi-squared distibution. What is better to use here?

My attempt:

Let's consider $\alpha = \frac{complications}{total}$.

Placebo parameter is $35/80$ and medicine A parameter is $49/75$.

$1.959$ is threshold for $N(0,1)$ with $0.95$ significance.

$$\frac{\theta - \theta_0}{se(\theta)} = ?$$

I suppose that I need put difference to the numerator. But I do not understand what to put to standard error and how to interpret the result.

Comment: I would definitely use a chi-squared test here. Or better yet, if you have access to a computer, Fisher's exact test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test

Comment: Can you explain why

Comment: Chi-sq test of independence gives substantially the same result as in my Answer. [Chi-sq statistic is essentially the square of Z statistic. Authors differ about the need for continuity correction to compute P-value).] As you can see there, I agree Fisher's Exact test is preferable.

Comment: @sooobus chi-squared is far easier to compute by hand and even easier to compute using a statistical programming language like R. Fisher's test, as it says in the name though, is exact although you would certainly need a computer to do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is output from Minitab statistical software comparing complication rates for Placebo (Sample 1) and Drug A (Sample 2). Of course, the smaller rate is preferable.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X   N  Sample p
1       45  80  0.562500
2       26  75  0.346667

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.215833
95% CI for difference:  (0.0628052, 0.368862)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 2.76  P-Value = 0.006

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.010
```

The Wald test is an 'asymptotic' test depending on a normal approximation
for large data. Sample sizes here are small for a drug trial. Thus, I would
prefer Fisher's Exact Test. However, both two-sided tests reject the
null hypothesis that placebo and drug have the same complication rate.
A one-sided test with the alternative that the drug has the smaller
complication rate has P-value 0.003 for the first test and 0.005 for Fisher's
Exact test.

*Note:* Formulas for the first test differ. Some texts base the standard error
on separately estimated variances and some on the combined rate $(45 + 26)/(90 + 75),$ suggested by the null hypothesis. The output shown is for separately estimated variances. (For the 'combined' standard error the results are
slightly different, but not enough different to change the conclusion to reject.) If this is for a class, you need to
use exactly the formula in your text or notes.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter we estimate is the ratio of patients with complications.

We have a parameter for placebo, which is $35/80$, and want to test a hypothesis that the other distribution (for other drug) is the same as placebo (which means that this medicine is just as effective as placebo).

A formula for the test:

$$\frac{\theta - \theta_0}{s / \sqrt n}.$$

$s$ is a mean sum of squared differences between sample elements (which are zeros and ones) and their mean (which for drug A is $26/75$).

$n$ is $75$.

We get the value 8.25 for the test value. It is more that 1.9 so test is not passed and the drug is placebo.

Comment: Your displayed equation cannot be a formula for the test statistic because it contains unknown parameter $\theta.$